# What cable do I need to connect this internal hard drive to my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-3

This is an image:

[image]

of an old (a few years) internal hard drive. It's Samsung model HD103SJ.

What cable do I need to connect this to a USB 3 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adapter like [this](https://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIV0GS3TC7471&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleBizMKPL-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleBizMKPL-PC-_-pla-_-External%20Enclosure-_-9SIV0GS3TC7471&gclid=CPrAjcPihM8CFYWAaQod02QDhw) would do the trick.

Comment: What are those ports to the right side of the SATA port? Is one of them the power port? Do I need an extra power cable?

Comment: Yes, it is for a power cable that is included. A 2.5" drive requires no additional power, but since your drive is a 3.5" it will need to use that included power cable.